# Highstocks compare update data points when redrawing

Tags: javascript, php, python, highcharts

I am using HighStock.js to graph a chart of cumulative data with a scrollbar. I have this.

```
 var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('PercentTotal', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
        zoomType: 'xy',
        events: {
            load: function(){
                this.xAxis[0].setExtremes(start, end);
            }
        }
    }, 
more stuff for the chart...etc
    plotOptions:{
            series: {
                compare: 'value'
            }
    },
    more stuff for the chart...etc
```

So I'm using series compare:value to redraw the lines so that they always start on the x-axis but this doesn't actually update the data points themselves. When I hover over the lines using the tooltip at the start of the lines, they are the original points in the series and have not been zero-adjusted.

Is there some way for me to grab the points of the start date of the range and then subtract that from all the other points in the range so that I can zero-center it.

I do the accumulation one-time in python and send it over through Jinja templates to Highcharts.

Comment: You can use a tooltip [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter). In the formatter you have access to all chart information, hovered points, series, data and grouped data so you can make any calculations you want - see example http://jsfiddle.net/rdrzbk4v/

Comment: How can I get the value of the point at a specific x coordinate? I can get the value of the min and max dates of the range selector but I'm not sure how to get the point from it.

Comment: By an x coordinate you mean pixels? If so, you can use [xAxis.toPixels()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Axis.toPixels) which translates pixels to axis scale

Comment: That's not what I mean. So my goal is to find the point.y of the first point within the range selected and then subtract that from all the other points in the range. Right now, I only have the point.x VALUE from the range selector but not the point itself. I've been trying to do a binary search over the point.series but because I'm using a range selector the series that is being returned looks like this, where it has a length of the normal series but its only returning the range that is selected. 

`[502 … 601]
[602 … 701]
[702 … 736]
length: 737`

Comment: I want the first point in this sub-array but I don't know how to get it since its  I can't just do array[0] because the index actually starts at 502.

Comment: Correction: I do not have the point.x VALUE. I just have a string containing the minDate of the range selector.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to do it. There's a point.series.points array that is an array of only the points being displayed.